# How to assign results of futures in Dart depending on which future produced them?

Tags: dart, future

In Dart, I want to run several costly functions, which are independent of each other, and assign the results to my variables, depending on which function produced them. Roughly a parallel version of this:

```dart
double x = getX();
double y = getY();
```

I'm thinking of something like this:

```dart
double x, y;
Future.wait([
  futureGetX(),
  futureGetY()
]).then((List results) {
  results.foreach((r) {
    // if(r is produced by futureGetX) x = r;
    // if(r is produced by futureGetY) y = r;
  }); 
});
```

and I don't know how to implement this `is produced by` part. A way would be to wrap the result of each function in a different class and, in the `then` part, check the class of the result:

```dart
if(r is wrapperForX) x = r.getValue();
if(r is wrapperForY) y = r.getValue();
```

but this seems very inelegant to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: How would we know which one produced the result? Does the one that didn't produce the result return null? Or do you just want to get the first result and ignore the 2nd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Randal I found a solution:

```
Future.wait([
  () async { x = await futureGetX(); } (),
  () async { y = await futureGetY(); } ()
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I think I got this. :)

Use closures:

```
Future.wait([
  () => { x = await futureGetX()},
  () => { y = await futureGetY()},
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was close enough. But the list elements need be Futures, not just functions. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for Futures in parallel, you use `Future.wait`, as you already noticed.
The results in the list returned (asynchronously) by `Future.wait` are in the *same order* as the original futures, so instead of using `forEach` you can just do:

```dart
x = results[0];
y = results[1];
```

Comment: Nice to know, but is it a hack or a feature?

Comment: Feature. I can see that it isn't actually documented (doh!), but I can promise you that it's intended to work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use FutureGroup from async package, FIFO behavior for the result list is documented: https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/async/1.13.3/async/FutureGroup-class.html